# How to load XML file from a Java project?

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, classpath

I am working with Intellij and my XML file is in the below path -

> C:\workspace\one\two\three\src\main\java\com\package\serv\ap\versionOne\fine.xsd

Now I am trying to read this XML file as I need to make `StreamSource` object from it. When I use absolute path, then it works fine -

```
StreamSource XSD = new StreamSource(new File("C:\\workspace\\one\\two\\three\\src\\main\\java\\com\\package\\serv\\ap\\versionOne\\fine.xsd"));
```

But the above is not the right way to  do it as it will not work in other machines. So I tried using `getResourceAsStream` but that doesn't work for me as I get everything as null inside `StreamSource` object

```
StreamSource XSD = new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("fine.xsd"));
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing while trying to load xml file?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SimY4 I am just trying to find a way to read the XML file using the right way not with the absolute path since it won't work in other machines. I am not sure how would I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your xsd file on the classpath. Then you will be be able to read the file the same way regardless whether you are in IntelliJ or running somewhere else.

In IntelliJ add the folder to the project classpath the same way you would for a jar file.

When you build a jar file to run your application elsewhere include the xsd in the root of the jar file.

Then you can use getResourceAsStream() no matter where your application is running from.

Answer (score 0):

There are Classes like **DocumentBuilderFactory** which  enables applications to obtain a parser that produces DOM object trees from XML documents &  & **DocumentBuilder** used to obtain DOM Document instances from an XML document. [DocumentBuilderFactory - JDK API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) & [DocumentBuilder - JDK API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html).

**For demo example :** [How To Read XML File In Java – (DOM Parser)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

This will give you the pwd and you can navigate from there.

Comment: I should be using this in the class where I am suppose to read the XML file right?

Comment: Yes exactly, capture the returned value in the string.

Comment: Ohkk after getting that, then how do I use it?

Comment: You will get the pwd from it(for eg. if your current project is AWT, you will get path to AWT). From there you can go to your pakages(i.e src/main/java.....).

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. He is wanting to know how to read the file from the classpath regardless if he is in IntelliJ or if his application is running elsewhere.